# API LinkedIn for Company

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'd like to publish, modify and delete posts on a linkedin company page from a form on my site. What API product do I need to set this up? I'm thinking of using the Advertising API product with the "organization" requests to set this up.